# Не видит айпи докер контейнера

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, docker, ip

Не могу сделать запрос правильный с фронтэнда на бэк когда запущено через докер

Все 3 контейнера (фронт на реакте, бэк на ноде и постгрес) запускаю через docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:

  front-react:
    build:
      context: ./client
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    depends_on:
      - server-dev
    volumes:
      - ./client:/client
      - /client/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  server-dev:
    build:
      context: ./server
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./server:/server
      - /server/node_modules


  database:
    image: postgres:14.2-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=rssParser
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    
volumes:
  server-dev:
```

Все отлично работает, фронт запустился и работает, бэк тоже запущен и в базу постоянно закидывает новости через парсер. Но стоит мне сделать запрос через ссылку к базе типа:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5002/api/login
```

Мне выдает ошибку. И через постман тоже! Вероятно ошибка в айпи сервера, и оно должно быть не локалхост, а или название докер контейнера или айпи его, но и они тоже не дают результат...
Пробовал еще делать запросы:

```
http://rss_parser_server-dev_1:5002/api/registration
http://localhost.rss_parser_server-dev_1:5002/api/registration
http://rss_parser_server-dev:5002/api/registration
http://172.20.0.3:5002/api/registration
```

вот контейнеры которые запущены:

```
          Name                        Command               State                    Ports                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rss_parser_database_1      docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp,:::5432->5432/tcp
rss_parser_front-react_1   docker-entrypoint.sh /bin/ ...   Up      0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp,:::3000->3000/tcp
rss_parser_server-dev_1    docker-entrypoint.sh /bin/ ...   Up      0.0.0.0:5002->5002/tcp,:::5002->5002/tcp
```

вот айпи сервера:

```
sudo docker inspect rss_parser_server-dev_1 | grep "IPAddress"
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.20.0.3"
```

Я не понимаю где я облажался... помогите пожалуйста.
Может где то что то надо в хост прописать, но тогда почему и через постман не работает запросы...

Ошибку в постман выдает:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.3:5002

Comment: вы пытаетесь сделать запрос из фронта на бек? тогда адрес должен выглядеть так `http://server-dev:5002/api/login`, нужно использовать имя сервиса из docker-compose файла

Comment: Да, пытаюсь сделать запрос из фронта на бек, но получают ошибку независимо от ссылки  ```Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://server-dev:5002/api/registration. (Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос CORS). Код состояния: (null).```   ну здесь причина не в корсах, через постман тоже не проходят запросы...

Comment: как раз причина в CORS, а из постман http://server-dev:5002/api/login работать и не должно, этот адрес будет доступен только внутри сети докера. Из постмана должен работать http://localhost:5002/api/login

Comment: Та как раз дело в том что я использовал миллион вариантов этого айпи что в постмане, что на клиенте...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все теперь стало понятно) два дня поиска не там где надо показали что надо кое где убрать,а именно был файл server.js:

```
require(`dotenv`).config();
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5002
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1', () => {console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT} port!`)});
```

Поменял на вот такой:

```
require(`dotenv`).config();
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5002
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT} port!`)});
```

Все, запросы можно делать, все ок!)